# why not reference wcf service from web project?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, architecture

In a traditional way of thinking (remember [DNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_DNA)?) we're supposed to architect our application by separating layers into services. When implementing an ASP.NET MVC application, why should you really implement an extra service and wrap your WCF references into a separate dll, rather than having the web application reference the WCF directly?

I can think of two arguments, and some thoughts on those:

- Keep the code in once place (well, this is still done when you have the wCF!)
- Reusable service when other systems need the service (well, what if its internal to the application?)

On the other hand, people might argument for over-architecture as implementing alot of layers just bring more complexity to the solution and does not yield the benefits expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not actually a fan of introducing extra dlls just "because". Been there; ot the t-shirt with the dependency graph on it. If you can't clearly define the benefit *in your environment/context*, then do the simplest thing - which may well be reference from the web app.

I've heard the argument of allowing re-use, but to counter: soap/mex is already pretty-much defining this. Another argument is testability, isolation, separation etc; and it all depends on how much benefit these give **you** (or rather: your team) in **your** usage.

One *very valid* case for a separate dll here is when (mainly for internal apps) you are sharing a DTO library between the WCF server and client, so that both have rich objects rather than simple shadows. Bit I gather (from the tone) that this doesnt apply in this case.

Comment: It's an asp.net mvc app with a service layer using POCO classes against EF4.